# How to serialize complex model to xml format wcf

Tags: wcf, soapui, wcf-data-services, wcf-ria-services, wcf-binding

I am developing a wcf application which is taking c# request model as an input and returning complex response c# model after populating data in it from database.  I am using SOAP UI client tool to test my service.

Earlier i had decorated my contract with XmlSerializerFormat attribute  and after submitting request i was able to get the response in Result tab of SOAP UI tool. Below is the code snippet of it :

```
  [ServiceContract]
  [XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    Employee GetData(Employee value);
}



  [DataContract]
    public class Employee
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }

         [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

         public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

But now due to some reasons i have removed XmlSerializerFormat attribute from contract and i want default serializer to take care of it. But when i am submitting the request from client , my response model is populating with results but Response tab of SOAP UI shows empty response.

During Response model population when i am removing certain properties from response model, i am able to see result in response tab of SOAP UI tool.

Is Default serializer in  facing some issues while serializing some of property of my model. Any other attribute apart from  XmlSerializerFormat ?

Please let me know where i am lacking or is there any alternative of XmlSerializerFormat attribute.

Thnx in Advance

Comment: Do you want to save the response xml  from soapui too?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding DataContract attribute to the Employee on the class level and DataMember attribute to its properties that you want to be serialized. If it has complex property types of its own they also may need to be decorated similarly. Default serializer in WCF is DataContract serializer FYI.

Comment: Dogu Arslan : It was  already there. I am having a property of complex array type in Employee model and i am populating that array from DB. While passing NULL to that property explicitly i am able to see the response in SOAP Client's response tab. else not. I have also increase the size of response message from setting but not working.